# Can't get value to be assigned to variable

Tags: python

```
import random
print('-\n')
begin=int(raw_input('-\n')
end=int(raw_input('-\n')
rep=int(raw_input('-\n')
def dop():
    print random.randinterga
ivfhoierh
while count < rep:
    print do
    count = count + 1

print('Thanks for using this program!\n')
raw_input('press enter to continue')
```

Okay, so I really have no idea what iv've done wrong but I keep getting a syntax error and IDLE highlights 'end'.

Edit: C

Comment: Please explain what your code is supposed to do and read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to know how to put together a good question.

Comment: To help you out a bit, you are missing a closing parentheses when you call `float` for `begin`, `end` and `rep`. You are also not actually calling `do`. You need to actually call it like this: `do()`. That should get you a bit further.

Comment: Also i forget that i have to use int. Thanks alot @idjaw and

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess you are using Python 2, judging by raw_input.
Correct your code to:

```
import random
print 'Hi, I will print out random intergers from a range you specify.\n'
#No need for parenthesis
begin=float(raw_input('Please enter the starting range. \n'))
end=float(raw_input('Please enter the end range. \n'))
rep=float(raw_input('Please enter how many times you cant to repeat the function. \n'))
# ERROR you forgot an extra parenthesis on the end of each of the last 3 lines.
def do():
    print random.randint(begin, end)

count = 0
while count < rep:
    do()  # <- Parenthesis, and no need to print.
    count = count + 1

print 'Thanks for using this program!\n' #No need for parenthesis
raw_input('press enter to continue')
```

Also this:

```
count = 0
while count < rep:
    do()  # <- Parenthesis, and no need to print.
    count = count + 1
```

Can be replaced by this:

```
for count in range(rep):
    do()
```

Comment: yeah, it doesnt run.

Comment: @Looi Corrected, check again. Found your syntax error.

Comment: @Looi Mark the answer as Accepted (Under the upvote/downvote arrows) in order for other users to see that the question was helpful.

Comment: @Looi FWIW advising to not put parentheses around a print is bad advice. In Python 3, print is a method and most definitely needs parentheses. So it's best to get used to it in Python 2 to make your life easier if you move to 3.

Comment: Even better, use `from __future__ import print_function` in Python 2 to *force* you to use parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do this:

```
import random
print 'I will print out random integers from a range you specify.'

begin = int(raw_input('Please enter the starting range: '))
end = int(raw_input('Please enter the end range: '))
rep = int(raw_input('Please enter the repeat value: '))

def get_random():
    return random.randint(begin, end)

for _ in range(rep):
    print get_random()
```

Attention to detail is so important.

Problems addressed:

- Mismatched parentheses
- Inconsistent assignments
- Inconsistent use of `print`
- Personal preference over returning, then printing
- Renamed function `do()` for clarity
- `raw_input()` doesn't need `\n` new lines
- `randint()` gets upset generating `ValueError: non-integer arg 1 for randrange()` on float values; cast the `raw_input()` accordingly
- (Minor) Corrected spelling in output
- Replaced while loop with for loop, removing unneeded variable `count` and assignments

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's a shame this didn't get accepted. Aw well. +1.